# How to detect html button in iOS objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

I am new in iOS and I am trying to detect html button when ever user click. Is it possible in iOS?  I have gone through many example but many are not working. please tell me how to detect html button in iOS?

Comment: You are looking for javascript bridge. https://github.com/ShawnFoo/SwiftWebViewBridge

Comment: yes if its possible

Comment: is this in swift language?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you are using WKWebView. Use the user content controller at configuration time to add a script message handler:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkusercontentcontroller/1537172-add

In the web page, you either already have the needed JavaScript (if this is your web page) or you inject the needed JavaScript into the page, so that the message handler fires when the button is tapped.